# Why can you have a HashSet of objects of that class

Tags: java

I'm battling to understand why this is possible. I'm a java newbie and don't understand how you can have a collection of any type (lists or sets) be of type Example. I'm battling to understand both the recursive nature of this as well as why this is used.

```
class Example {
    private Set<Example> setExample;
    //....
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"recursive nature"*? There is no recursion, you just declared a `Set` that can hold references to objects of type `Example`.

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks. How can you have references to the same type as the class type?

Comment: Here's an example from everyday life: your computer's filesystem has directories (aka folders), which can themselves contain directories. In Java, you can imagine a class Directory with a `Set<Directory> subdirectories`.

Comment: @yshavit. That analogy's great. It helped it "click" for me. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An object can contain references to other objects of the same class. It can even contain a reference to itself (though that may cause problems in some cases).

As to why this is used - objects in real life can (and often are) be related to other objects of the same type. A person is related to other persons (their family members), a web page can refer to other web pages related to it, etc...

A common usage of such references in data structures are Nodes/Links, which are used to implement linked lists and trees. Each Node/Link holds some data, in addition to a reference to one or more other Nodes/Links related to the current Node/Link.

```
class TreeNode<T> {
    T data;
    private List<TreeNode<T>> children;
}
```

Comment: +1, but you should define reference, since that's the important point. You're not storing a whole `Example` object inside another, just a reference to it, which is why there's nothing recursive going on.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations guys. @GKFX please elaborate on that point of only storing a reference.

Comment: Objects are stored in memory, and in languages such as C++ you can have a pointer to an object, which is just a number giving you its location in the memory. Regardless of how big the object is, you can access it with just one number, so an object can store a pointer to itself without actually containing itself. Java is similar with its use of references, but unlike C++ you can't actually see the number.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible, because a variable of type `Example` is just a reference to an object of this type. Java is trying to hide what other languages call pointers.

Answer (score 3):

The question if this possible or not depends on the rest of your code. For example

```
class Example {
    private Set<Example> setExample;

    public Example() {
        setExample = new HashSet<Example>();
}
```

Will create new empty container that can hold `Example` objects. There isn't any problem with it. However

```
class Example {
    private Set<Example> setExample;

    public Example() {
        setExample = new HashSet<Example>();
        setExample.add(new Example());
}
```

Will create sort of infinite loop and you will get `OutOfMemoryError` as each creation of `Example` will create another `Example` instance and so on. However, this is not recursion.

Comment: It's that first case which I'm referring to. Each element in the set refers to an object of type Example which then contains another set referring to other objects of Example... That keeps going right?

Comment: @JonJavaK Basically you are correct, but the `Set` will only have `Example` instances if you add it those instances, so this is true only to a point.